# Degree of field extension $F(x) / F(x^2 + 1 / x^2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $y=\frac{x^4+1}{x^2} \in F(x)$. Then $g(x)=0$ for the polynomial $g(s) = (s^4+1)-ys^2$. How to show that it is the minimal polynomial over the field $F(y)$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that both $x$ and $-x$ are roots of $g(s)$. Using the polynomial division algorithm, we can write $g(s)$ as
$$
g(s) = (s + x)(s - x)(s + 1/x)(s - 1/x).
$$

As long as $\operatorname{char}(F) \ne 2$, we see that the given extension is the splitting field of a separable polynomial. Thus, it is Galois. We immediately see the following automorphisms: $x \mapsto x$, $x \mapsto -x$, $x \mapsto 1/x$ and $x \mapsto -1/x$. We conclude that the degree of the extension is $4$ and the polynomial $g(s)$ is minimal.

Comment: Dear @Georges, thanks for the comment. I'm not sure I follow. The degree of the extension $F(x) / F(y)$ is at most $4$ since $g$ has degree $4$. The extension is Galois, being the splitting field of a separable polynomial. We've found $4$ automorphisms; hence the degree is at least $4$. We conclude that the degree is $4$. Why do we need to show that $g$ is irreducible?

Comment: Dear Ayman, you are perfectly right ! I sincerely apologize for my unfortunate and unfair comment, which I have of course deleted.

Comment: I also have advised Jytug [in a comment to his question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1233408/3217) to come  here  and read your solution to his problem .

Comment: No problem at all, dear @Georges. I always appreciate your comments and feedback. Thank you for linking to my answer. I think I'll mark that question as a duplicate of this.