# Field extension in rational functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I'm facing the following problem:

Let $ F $ be a field, and let $ F(x)  $ denote all rational functions over $ F $ (functions of form $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$, where $ P,Q$ are polynomials over $ F $). Find the degree $$ \left[ F(x): F \left( x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right] $$

Actually it's a homework exercise and I'm not sure what $ F \left( x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}\right) $ is supposed to mean. Is it the smallest field contained in $ F(x) $ containing $ F \cup \{x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}\} $?

If so, how do I find the degree of the extension? I'm not even sure where to begin.

Comment: I've seen this posted a few times in the past couple of days. Where is it from?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure - my professor sends us exercises weekly in a .pdf form

Comment: Me, too!  I've also seen it and variants posted here.  Mayber Jytug's professor got it by surfing MSE!!! ;-)

Comment: Are there any answers to that question? To be honest, I couldn't find any threads about this exercise which made me think it's not been asked before

Comment: Write $x^2+\frac1{x^2}$ as $f(x)/g(x)$ and the degree is the degree of $f$ or $g$, whichever is larger.  This is a basic theorem you should be able to find easily.

Comment: You might have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1230287/show-that-the-polynomial-is-minimal; Prold, the author of that question also asked one similar to yours but deleted it.  That's all I know . . . Cheers!

Comment: @GregoryGrant thank you - I'm not sure why that is though. Where can I search for this theorem you mentioned?

Comment: The degree is 4: [Jacobson, Basic Algebra II](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Basic_Algebra_II.html?id=hn75exNZZ-EC&redir_esc=y) Theorem 8.36, page 514 (of the first edition).

Comment: I now realize that @Ayman Hourieh is too modest to mention that he gave a perfect answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1230383/3217): I suggest you read his answer and upvote it !